# Adicionar elementos a um textarea por ordem de checagem de checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Pois bem pessoal gostaria de saber quem pode me ajudar. Achei esse script nesse forum americano http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/170591-solved-checkbox-populating-a-text-area funciona o script, literalmente faz aparecer os valores marcados dentro da textarea, com tudo ele adiciona os itens seguindo a ordem da lista das checkboxes.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Fruits</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID)
     {
        var checkGroup = checkObj.form[checkObj.name];
        var checkGroupLen = checkGroup.length;
        var valueList = new Array();
        for (var i=0; i<checkGroupLen; i++)
        {
           if (checkGroup[i].checked)
           {
              valueList[valueList.length] = checkGroup[i].value;
           }
        }
        document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = valueList.join('\r\n');
        return;
     }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form name="myform">
     <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Oranges" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Oranges</font><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apples"  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Apples</font><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Grapes"  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Grapes</font><br>
     <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="txt1" id="txt1" style="color:#808080"  readonly></textarea>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Agora eis a minha pergunta, gostaria de saber como posso alterar isso de forma que ele coloque os valores na textarea adicionando os itens na ordem em que eu ativar um checkbox, ou seja, digamos que eu tenha itens 1,2 e 3; se eu adicionar do jeito em que o script está no momento nessa ordem 2,1,3 a ordem colocada dentro da textarea será 1,2,3 gostaria que seguindo o exemplo ficasse na ordem que marquei, ou seja, 2,1,3. Isso é possível? Se sim, alguém poderia me ajudar? Sou iniciante ainda e isso me ajudaria muito.

---

Valeu funcionou mais tipo se não for incomodar veja só achei ele com complemento com um botão full teria como me ajudar com isso pondo no código que vc já me passo e agradeço mesmo colocando nele a função full ? Como esta no código abaixo antigo que postei mais complemento.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID)
 {
    var checkGroup = checkObj.form[checkObj.name];
    var checkGroupLen = checkGroup.length;
    var valueList = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<checkGroupLen; i++)
    {
       if (checkGroup[i].checked)
       {
          valueList[valueList.length] = checkGroup[i].value;
       }
    }
    document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = valueList.join('\r\n');
    return;
 }

    function checkAllBox(formObj, fieldName, checkedState)
 {
    if(formObj[fieldName].length)
    {
       var fieldLen = formObj[fieldName].length;
       for(var i=0; i<fieldLen; i++)
       {
          formObj[fieldName][i].checked = checkedState;
          addToList(formObj[fieldName][i], 'txt1');
       }
    }
    else
    {
       formObj[fieldName].checked = checkedState;
       addToList(formObj[fieldName], 'txt1');
    }
    return;
 }
```

```
<form name="myform">
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="all"  onClick="checkAllBox(this.form, 'fruit[]', this.checked);" /><b>Check All</b><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Oranges" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1');" /><span style="color:#808080">Oranges</span><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apples"  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1');" /><span style="color:#808080">Apples</span><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Grapes"  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1');" /><span style="color:#808080">Grapes</span><br>
 <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="txt1" id="txt1" style="color:#808080" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

Comment: Coloque o que você conseguiu desenvolver até agora na pergunta.

Comment: Quando fizer perguntas, tente não deixar o título tão vago, e se atente ao máximo nas tags adicionadas. Para essa pergunta em específico a tag **php** é desnecessária já que o código tratado diz respeito apenas a HTML e JavaScript, ou seja, do lado do cliente (navegador).

Comment: Uma dica: Procure entender o código antes de postar. Muita coisa pode ser resolvida apenas entendendo o código. Se você não tem conhecimentos na linguagem, é uma ótima hora para aprender. Colocar códigos aqui para que outros façam por você não é a melhor solução. Uma hora o povo fica mais chato como o internacional e não vão fazer o seu trabalho. Nada pessoal, só que essa comunidade é para ajudar pessoas com dúvidas e problemas de programação e não fazer o trabalho ou pensar pelos outros. Qualquer coisa, dê uma olhada na [FAQ](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando jQuery isso que você busca deve ser bem mais fácil e otimizado, mas baseado no que entendi que você quer e no script encontrado no link passado como exemplo, você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fruits</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Array que guarda a ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos
      var listCheckedOptions = [];

      function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID)
      {
        //Remove do array caso o elemento já esteja inserido
        if (listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj.value) >= 0) {
          listCheckedOptions.splice(listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj.value), 1);
        } else { //Adiciona casojá esteja inserido
          listCheckedOptions.push(checkObj.value);
        }

//        alert(listCheckedOptions); //debug para verificar os elementos inseridos
        document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = ""; //Limpa o textarea
        document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = listCheckedOptions.join('\r\n'); //Adiciona no textarea

        return;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Oranges" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Oranges</font><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apples"  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Apples</font><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Grapes"  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Grapes</font><br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="txt1" id="txt1" style="color:#808080"  readonly></textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Repare que a alteração foi feita apenas na função **addToList** e foi criado o array **listCheckedOptions**. Mas tente fazer algo parecido usando jQuery... Espero ter ajudado.

**Editado**

Conforme pedido, para que o código funcione também com a opção de "Checar Todos" pode-se usar a função **checkAllBox** da seguinte forma:

```
  function checkAllBox(formObj, fieldName, checkedState)
  {
    if(formObj[fieldName].length)
    {
      var fieldLen = formObj[fieldName].length;
      for(var i=0; i<fieldLen; i++)
      {
        //Call addToList function only when element isn't checked and is checking all
        //or when element is checked and is uncheckin all
        if ((formObj[fieldName][i].checked == false && checkedState) || 
        (formObj[fieldName][i].checked == true && !checkedState))
        {
          formObj[fieldName][i].checked = checkedState;
          addToList(formObj[fieldName][i], 'txt1');
        }
      }
    }
    return;
  }
```

Veja a checagem que é feita dentro da função. Só é chamada a função que já existia **addToList** quando o elemento testado não está checado e está se marcando todos, ou quando o elemento testado está marcado e está se desmarcando todos.

Não esqueça de adicionar o check box que será responsável por marcar/desmarcar todos.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" value="all"  onClick="checkAllBox(this.form, 'fruit[]', this.checked);" /><b>Check All</b>
```

Lembrando que existem várias maneiras de implementar, umas até mais limpas em relação a ter pouco código, só tentei utilizar o código que você havia postado.

Abraço!

Comment: Obrigada mais e o botão full que tinha como e que eu coloco ?

Comment: Adriano, quer dar uma olhada no novo código do user (na resposta que ele colocou que é uma continuação da pergunta) e melhorar a sua resposta?

Comment: Posso responder assim que arranjar um tempinho. Se alguém quiser responder antes fique a vontade. De qualquer forma assim que arranjar um tempo arrumo esse script @user14033.

Comment: Pronto @user14033, veja se dessa forma seu problema é resolvido.

Comment: Valeu cara essa isso mesmo que eu queria muito obrigada pela ajuda desculpe ter demorado tanto para responder fiquei sem internet por uns dias desde já nova mente muito obrigada pela ajuda esse script sera muito útil para mim e vou ver o uso de Jquery como aconselhado mais esse ai já esta de bom tamanho para mim uma vez que faz o que eu queria ^_^