# Inserir os valores de Checkbox dentro de um uma Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu estou fazendo uma página que auxilia Operadores de Monitoramento (Monitoramento de carga), e eu preciso inserir vários formulários em uma mesma página. Veja o exemplo de um deles:

```js
//Array que guarda a ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos
var listCheckedOptions = [];

function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID)
{
//Remove do array caso o elemento já esteja inserido
if (listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj.value) >= 0) {
listCheckedOptions.splice(listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj.value), 1);
} else { //Adiciona caso já esteja inserido
listCheckedOptions.push(checkObj.value);
}

//        alert(listCheckedOptions); //debug para verificar os elementos inseridos
document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = ""; //Limpa o textarea
document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = listCheckedOptions.join('\r\n'); //Adiciona no textarea

return;
}

function copiarTextotxt1() {
var textoCopiado = document.getElementById("txt1");
textoCopiado.select();
document.execCommand("Copy");
alert("Texto Copiado: " + textoCopiado.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form001">

<input type="checkbox" name="cabecalho[]" id="cabecalho" value="Informamos que o motorista não está cumprindo o procedimento correto pois o mesmo: &#10;" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><label for="cabecalho"> Cabeçalho</label></p>

</br>

<input type="checkbox" name="opcao1[]" id="opcao1" value="(X) Não informa início de viagem."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><label for="opcao1"> Não informa início de viagem</label></p>
      
<input type="checkbox" name="opcao2[]" id="opcao2" value="(X) Não informa paradas."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><label for="opcao2"> Não informa paradas</label></p>

<input type="checkbox" name="opcao5[]" id="opcao5" value="(X) Não informa reinício de viagem."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><label for="opcao5"> Não informa reinício de viagem</label></p>

</br>

<input type="checkbox" name="rodape[]" id="rodape" value="&#10;Solicitamos que o motorista seja orientado blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá..."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><label for="rodape"> Rodapé</label>

</form>

</br>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="txt1" id="txt1" placeholder="Instruções de uso:&#10;&#10;1° - Selecione a opção 'Cabeçalho'.&#10;2° - Selecione o(s) procedimento(s) incorreto(s) do motorista.&#10;3° - Selecione a opção 'Rodapé'.&#10;4° - Clique no botão 'Copiar Texto'.   " style="color:#000000"  readonly></textarea>

</br>

<button onClick="copiarTextotxt1()">Copiar Texto</button>
```

O código para inserir os valores conforme são checados, eu encontrei aqui mesmo ([Adicionar elementos a um textarea por ordem de checagem de checkbox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28241/adicionar-elementos-a-um-textarea-por-ordem-de-checagem-de-checkbox)).

Mas o problema é que quando eu crio um novo formulário dentro da mesma página, os formulários entram em conflito.

Eu preciso de um código que permita pegar os dados do formulário com id=x e insira no textarea com id=y, entende?

Ou qualquer outra solução é bem vinda, desde que eu consiga inserir vários formulários na mesma página sem que entrem em conflito.

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema ocorre pois a função *addToList* modifica sempre a mesma array e a função *copiarTextotxt* copia sempre o texto do mesmo textarea.

Para solucionar Você tornar as funções genéricas, para que aceitem modificações em qualquer array ou textarea.
como a seguir:

A função "*addToList*" agora recebe um parametro adicional, a lista de opções marcadas a qual você pretende modificar(ex a *listCheckedOptions*).
**Você deverá criar uma array para cada form que for usar**, no caso criei a *listCheckedOptions* e *listCheckedOptions2*

a função "*copiarTextotxt*" agora tambem recebe o id do textarea o qual você pretende copiar o texto.

adicione esses novos parametros na propriedade onClick nos checkboxes  e no Botão de "Copiar texto"  de cada form e voilá.

Eis um exemplo com 2 forms:

```js
//Array que guarda a ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos
var listCheckedOptions = [];
var listCheckedOptions2 = [];

function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID,list)
{
//Remove do array caso o elemento já esteja inserido
if (list.indexOf(checkObj.value) >= 0) {
list.splice(list.indexOf(checkObj.value), 1);
} else { //Adiciona caso já esteja inserido
list.push(checkObj.value);
}

//        alert(list); //debug para verificar os elementos inseridos
document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = ""; //Limpa o textarea
document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = list.join('\r\n'); //Adiciona no textarea

return;
}

function copiarTextotxt(id) {
var textoCopiado = document.getElementById(id);
textoCopiado.select();
document.execCommand("Copy");
alert("Texto Copiado: " + textoCopiado.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form001">

<input type="checkbox" name="cabecalho[]" id="cabecalho" value="Informamos que o motorista não está cumprindo o procedimento correto pois o mesmo: &#10;" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1',listCheckedOptions)"><label for="cabecalho"> Cabeçalho</label></p>

</br>

<input type="checkbox" name="opcao1[]" id="opcao1" value="(X) Não informa início de viagem."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1',listCheckedOptions)"><label for="opcao1"> Não informa início de viagem</label></p>
  
<input type="checkbox" name="opcao2[]" id="opcao2" value="(X) Não informa paradas."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1',listCheckedOptions)"><label for="opcao2"> Não informa paradas</label></p>

<input type="checkbox" name="opcao5[]" id="opcao5" value="(X) Não informa reinício de viagem."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1',listCheckedOptions)"><label for="opcao5"> Não informa reinício de viagem</label></p>

</br>

<input type="checkbox" name="rodape[]" id="rodape" value="&#10;Solicitamos que o motorista seja orientado blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá..."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1', listCheckedOptions)"><label for="rodape"> Rodapé</label>

</form>

</br>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="txt1" id="txt1" placeholder="Instruções de uso:&#10;&#10;1° - Selecione a opção 'Cabeçalho'.&#10;2° - Selecione o(s) procedimento(s) incorreto(s) do motorista.&#10;3° - Selecione a opção 'Rodapé'.&#10;4° - Clique no botão 'Copiar Texto'.   " style="color:#000000"  readonly></textarea>

</br>

<button onClick="copiarTextotxt('txt1')">Copiar Texto</button>
<form name="form001">

<input type="checkbox" name="cabecalho[]" id="cabecalho" value="Informamos que o motorista não está cumprindo o procedimento correto pois o mesmo: &#10;" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt2', listCheckedOptions2)"><label for="cabecalho"> Cabeçalho</label></p>

</br>

<input type="checkbox" name="opcao1[]" id="opcao1" value="(X) Não informa início de viagem."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt2', listCheckedOptions2)"><label for="opcao1"> Não informa início de viagem</label></p>
      
<input type="checkbox" name="opcao2[]" id="opcao2" value="(X) Não informa paradas."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt2', listCheckedOptions2)"><label for="opcao2"> Não informa paradas</label></p>

<input type="checkbox" name="opcao5[]" id="opcao5" value="(X) Não informa reinício de viagem."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt2', listCheckedOptions2)"><label for="opcao5"> Não informa reinício de viagem</label></p>

</br>

<input type="checkbox" name="rodape[]" id="rodape" value="&#10;Solicitamos que o motorista seja orientado blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá..."  onClick="addToList(this, 'txt2', listCheckedOptions2)"><label for="rodape"> Rodapé</label>

</form>

</br>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="txt2" id="txt2" placeholder="Instruções de uso:&#10;&#10;1° - Selecione a opção 'Cabeçalho'.&#10;2° - Selecione o(s) procedimento(s) incorreto(s) do motorista.&#10;3° - Selecione a opção 'Rodapé'.&#10;4° - Clique no botão 'Copiar Texto'.   " style="color:#000000"  readonly></textarea>

</br>

<button onClick="copiarTextotxt('txt2')">Copiar Texto</button>
```

Comment: Tenho conhecimento básico em criação de páginas. Fiquei horas tentando solucionar esse problema que você resolveu de forma rápida e didática.

Quero lhe agradecer imensamente, pois você resolveu um problema enorme para mim. Agora poderei pôr em prática todo o meu projeto.

Muitíssimo obrigado! Abraço.